# Drupal view field

Tags: drupal, view, field

In Drupal, I would like to display some user related nodes on their "My Account" page. I would like to do so by creating a View that i would add as a field on the user entity (through admin/config/people/accounts/display). I could use Computed Field in order to load and render the view but that is not very convenient as it requires me to write PHP code.

In short, is there a module that allows to add dummy fields containing a view in the "manage display" sections of entities?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd consider asking this over at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [Viewfield](http://drupal.org/project/viewfield). This allows you to reference a view and renders it.